# Question about calling .bind() on onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this code:

```
onClick={this.handleSortByChange.bind(this, sortByOptionValue)}
```

Does the handleSortByChange function get bound and called with a parameter of sortByOptionValue... or does it simply just get bound?

As far as it works in the code I am looking at, it is getting called.

Thanks!

Comment: It should only be bound, not called immediately called. Do you have a minimum reproducible example of the unwanted behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `bind` function on render, not when the `onClick` event happens.

The `bind` function, when executed returns a new function, so this is what is being passed to `onClick`.

In your case, you are binding on render, and executing `handleSortByChange` on the click event.

Comment: Ok, where does it state that the bind happens on render?

Comment: What do you think you are passing to onClick? Are you passing the bind function, or the result of executing the bind function?